# How to add TimeZone class to a Windows 8 Phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to use the TimeZone class in a Windows 8 Phone app that I am working on. For some reason I cannot use the TimeZone variable. That is I cannot declare anything as being type TimeZone. I tried making a Windows 8 form app and it works fine there. I am adding:

using System;

at the top of my files. I would greatly appreciate a response.

Comment: Which member you want to access from `TimeZone` class?

Comment: TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TimeZoneInfo localZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
string text = String.Format("{0}{1}:{2:00} ({3})",
    (localZone.BaseUtcOffset >= TimeSpan.Zero) ? "" : "-",
    Math.Abs(localZone.BaseUtcOffset.Hours), 
    Math.Abs(localZone.BaseUtcOffset.Minutes),
    TimeZoneInfo.Local.DisplayName);
```

Also check out [WinRTTimeZones](https://github.com/onovotny/WinRTTimeZones) on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue in my project. Solution for these TimeZone issues is [Noda](http://noda-time.blogspot.de/)
"Portable Class Library version (in the same package) which allows you to use Noda Time when writing applications for Windows Store, Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8. There are additional features around the time zone data available from TZDB, including location information and fuller Windows time zone ID mappings... and a few other bits and bobs, as you might expect."

I am using this library in my WP and Win8 project, so far works really good.